# Set company certificate as Trusted

Tags: ssl, certificates

My company gave me a file `company_CA.crt` that I need to use to access one of our customers website.

When I tried to add it on macOS, all I had to do was to click on the file, and then after imported, set it as "Always Trust".

I would like to do the same in Ubuntu, so I followed the next steps:

- Copied the CRT file to `usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my_company`
- Run `sudo update-ca-certificates`

But I cannot still open the website. Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 4):

- Check if the CA root certificate for your customer_web_site is known or not in your system.

  ```
  $ curl -I  https://customer_web_site
  curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
  ```

The CA certificate for customer_web_site server is (indeed) NOT known in the system.

File company_CA.crt must be in CRT format. (seems to be in this case)
If it is in PEM format, then you have to conver it (openssl x509 -in xxxx.pem -inform PEM -out xxxx.crt

- Install the CA file in Ubuntu

Copy the company_CA.crt file to new directory extra in /usr/share/ca-certificates

Let ubuntu pick-up that new CA certificate and install it in the Linux system

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

A menu will appear. Check option "ask" for Prompt for each new CA certificate. You will see your new certificate.

extra/company_CA.crt

Press space, to select that new CA certificate file and select OK.

uAt the end, you should see something like this:

1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Check if curl works without specifying the CA certificate file

```
$ curl -I https://customer_web_site
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2018 18:08:26 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 27 Jul 2018 12:09:02 GMT
ETag: "2c39-571f9fa3671da"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 11321
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

It works.

If you want to know more about Self Signed Certificates and how to use them, then check my [github](https://github.com/rlassche/ssl-factory).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* does the OP have to do? How? Do you have any additional [Tips or Tricks](/help/how-to-answer)? Please **[edit]** your post to add information before the system deletes this because of low quality...  **:-(**

Comment: On Ubuntu 18, this works as far as certificates are trusted by curl etc., Chromium and Firefox does not pickup the newly added certs

Comment: For those who still fail after this approach:  My company delivered both .pem files and .crt files.  However, I had to generate my own .crt files from .pem files using the above-mentioned tool in order for them to work correctly.